# If a circular plate is cut along a chord equal in length to the radius, what is the ratio of the areas of the two parts?

Tags: geometry, circles, area

A circular metal plate is cut into two segments along a chord equal in length to the radius. What is the ratio of the areas of the two segments.

The question above was give in a maths textbook under trigonometric functions. I have attempted to answer the question by drawing out a diagram as described in the question but it makes no sense. So could someone please help me figure out how to solve this question

Comment: Have you tried inserting line segments from the center to each end of the chord?

Comment: Please, understand that I provided the solution for the most general case. As shown in the other answers, you specific problem c=R can be solved in a much simpler manner.

Comment: yes thankyou. I understand how you did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment will provide you useful information.

In particular, the relation between the length of the chord and the angle. If you set c=R in the formula, you then see that the angle is defined by sin(theta / 2) = 1/2 which means that $\theta = \pi/3$.

Now, apply the formula for the area for the segment.

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: Shouldn't need to plug anything into chord length.  Drawing in radii to each end of the chord should form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: @Mike. I fully agree with you. I gave that for the most general case (say, c = 4 R / 3). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a graphic representation of the situation. Using the pythagorean theorem, you should be able to find the segment $\overline{OE}$. You could then find $\theta$, and then calculate a certain fraction of the circle, to which you add the area of the two triangles...

[image: Circle]

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [image: the following]

Let the radius be r.

Area of the minor segment PQN

= Area of the sector OPNQ – area of triangle OPQ

$= \frac {θ} {360} × πr^2 – \frac {1} {2}  × r^2  sin θ$

In this particular case,  (the length of the chord = the length of the radius) implies  θ = 60 degrees.

:

:

:

Comment: You are welcome. Hope it helps.